# Get index and title of a Tab Bar controller?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have this code, inside appdelegate.m (inside the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions)

```
 MeuPrimeiroViewController *primeiro = [[MeuPrimeiroViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav1 pushViewController:primeiro animated:YES];
    MeuSegundoViewController *segundo = [[MeuSegundoViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav2 pushViewController:segundo animated:YES];
    UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabbar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nil];
    nav1.tabBarItem.title = @"Primeiro";
    nav2.tabBarItem.title = @"Segundo";
    nav1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"um.png"];
    nav2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dois.png"];
```

And I need to know, how can I pick the index and the title when tab bar change? And where I put the code? Inside appdelegate? Where?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "pick the index"? Do you mean you wish to select a specific tab programmatically or do you mean you wish to be notified when the user selects a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick the index, set the tab bar controller's [selectedIndex](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW2) property.
To get the title of the view controller at selectedIndex, get the title from the tab bar controller's [selectedViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW1).

You can put the code in the tab bar controller itself, or in the contained view controllers if you prefer, using the view controller's [tabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW31) property to get at its properties.